# EXCEL クエリにてSQL serverに接続するとテーブルがロックされてしまう

Tags: sql, excel

タイトルの通り
ExcelのクエリからSQL Serverに接続するとテーブルが
Excelを終了するまでロックされてしまいます。

-接続ユーザーはSELECT権限のみ
-アプリケーションはMashup Engine
-クエリはリレーションあり、ビューあり

ExcelとMS SQLに詳しい方がいましたら助かります。

■追記
どうやらExcelのクエリはwith句を多用しているようで、
SQL Serverに負荷がかかっていたようです。
複雑なリレーションや無駄な処理を増やすとメモリへの負荷が上がり
サーバー側の処理が遅れ、ロックされているように感じられたのだと思います。

Comment: 何が問題で、何を解決したいのでしょうか？

Comment: ロックする原因がわかれば解決方法がわかると考えています。
SQLは複数のアクセスを想定しているのでSELECTのみでロックしてしまうものなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

SQL Serverのデフォルトの分離レベルはREAD COMMITTEDなので、Selectしたデータにはロックはかかります
ただし、そのロックが他のSelect文をブロックするとは限りません
本当にロックが問題なのかどうか確認するべきです

ロックが問題であるなら、サーバ側の設定を変えるのが可能であれば、スナップショット分離レベルを使用すれば解決するかもしれません